# Find the sequence logic

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

The sequence given is `1,7,38,182` and the fifth number is `798`.
The numbers only increase. Can anyone tell the **logic/formula** as to how this sequence is being generated?

Comment: There's nothing on OEIS

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! You should post what have you tried so far so we can help you better.

Comment: Technically, the answer is: The next term can be **any** number! There are infinite numbers that can be found on the sixth term.

Answer (score 2):

It could be anything. The finite differences are shown below. You can interpolate the given sequence with a polynomial of degree 4. But that is about it. It doesn't guarantee you that the sixth term will follow a pattern.

[image: Finite differences table]

Answer (score 0):

It could be any number.

If you assume a polynomial of degree $4$ since you only have $5$ data points
$$a_n=\frac 1 {24}\left(4872-10434 n+7673 n^2-2358 n^3+271 n^4 \right)$$ generates integer values $\forall n$.